# Fourier transform fancy "f"

Tags: math-fonts, amssymb

[image]

I have seen `\mathfrak{F}`, `\mathcal{F}` and `\mathscr{F}`, but none of those render the fancy fourier `f` given in the figure above. Is there any package for that?

Comment: Looks like the commercial Adobe Mathematical Pi fonts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @campa that the script-F glyph in the OP's screenshot comes from the commercial Adobe Mathematical Pi font. A close substitute that's free of charge is the "oblique" version of the `mathrsfs` package.

The lowercase-f letters in the OP's screenshot are some version Times Roman. To replicate this "look", I load the `newtxmath` package. (If you happen to have access to the [MathTime Professional Two](https://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) math font package, you'll get an even closer replica, especially for the "hat" symbol on top of the first instance of `f`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath} % for Times Roman clone math font
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa} % "oblique" version of mathrsfs

\begin{document}
$\hat{f}=\mathscr{F}(f)$
\end{document}
```